# I need 2 or more URL in one column in same item

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, url, nintex

I have two list I SharePoint 365, from an item in the list A I start a nintex workflow. The workflow make a new item in list B, make an Url with Id from the new item in List B. and update a column in list a with the Url displayed as an Id. No problem doing that... But when I try to do the same again, I would like the workflow to ad the new items Id after the one I made first, and so on, splitted by a comma, or semicolon og something else.

The Column Type for the Id in list A is a Hyperlink or picture. In the wookflow I use a build string action and a variable for previousId but it only works first time I run the workflow.

I cant figure out how I split the two or more id´s from list B

Here is the build sting action that Works, but only one time:
https://xxxxonline.sharepoint.com/teams/kslau/Audit/Lists/Audit%20%20Observationer/DispForm.aspx?ID=‎‏{Variable:OId}‌, ‎‏{Variable:OId}

Here is like what I want to do:
{Variable:PreviousOId}‌ , https://xxxxonline.sharepoint.com/teams/kslau/Audit/Lists/Audit%20%20Observationer/DispForm.aspx?ID=‎‏{Variable:OId}‌, ‎‏{Variable:OId}

I hope somebody could help me with this problem

Best regards Keld

Answer (score 2):

The native "Hyperlink or Picture" column can have only one hyperlink. For multiple, you need to use "Multiple lines of text" column with "Enhanced rich text" option. Then in Nintex Build String action use html to construct multiple hyperlinks.

Answer (score 2):

As the Ahmad suggested, the `Hyperlink or Picture` column cannot contains two links. But there is also an alternative instead of saving the complete HTML into column, and i would like to prefer them as you must not mix your Data with the UI elements while saving. Using the workflow add comma separated values, and then you can follow below approaches:

**For Classic Mode**

Take advantage of `CSR (Client Side Rendering)` provided by SharePoint to render the information as you require. This link contains all the information regarding CSR with example. https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-JS-2ed3538a

**For Modern Pages**

In Modern Pages, you can use `SPFx Extension - Field Customizer`. This also provides the same feature as CSR in classic pages. Follow this URL to learn more about field customizer https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/extensions/get-started/building-simple-field-customizer.